# PHP7 - Compile from Source x86/x64 Windows

Tags: c++, windows, dll, visual-studio-2015, php-7

I am trying to compile PHP7 from source based on the step by step guide : https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild

I have a Windows 7 x64 virtual machine, installed Visual Studio 2015 and ensured that C++ is installed.

Based on the instructions, all I need to do is open the *Developer Command Prompt for VS2015* and run the relevant `buildconf`, `configure ...` and `nmake` commands.

What I am not clear is how do I compile DLLs for x64 and x86. The ones compiled with this method appear to be x64 so far.

For past VC versions I would either use the `setenv /xp /x86 /release` command (VC9) or use the command prompt for x86 for VC11.

Any pointers are more than welcome.

Comment: `envp`, `argv`, `nullptr`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For VC14 you will use the same command prompt to compile DLLs for both architectures.

To do so you will need to run the `vcvarsall.bat` command with the necessary architecture parameter before compiling.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx

Credits for the pointers [kerrek-sb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb)